# KendoReact TreeView with CheckBoxes after setting CheckBox default value to true, CheckBox is not working

Tags: checkbox, treeview

After setting default checked value to true for TreeView CheckBox, CheckBox is not working and I'am not able to click anymore on checkbox.

[image]

This is the code. TreeView inside Expansion panel

```
  <ExpansionPanel
              title={"Expension panel"}
              expanded={expanded === item.id}
              tabIndex={0}
              key={item.id}
              onAction={(event) => {
                setExpanded(event.expanded ? "" : item.id);
              }}
            >
              <Reveal>
                {expanded === item.id && (
                  <ExpansionPanelContent>
                    <div>
                      <TreeView
                      data={processTreeViewItems(treeData, {
                        check: check,
                      })}
                      checkboxes={true}
                      onCheckChange={onCheckChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  </ExpansionPanelContent>
                )}
              </Reveal>
            </ExpansionPanel>
```

treeData

```
const treeData = match9.combo_data.map(item => { return  {text:item.naziv,id:item.id, checked:item.status ? true : false } })
```

Any help please?